# Reg ex - find part of string

Tags: regex

I've got data of this type (repeated many times):

```
@@@FFDFFHHHHHJJFFHGIJJJJGI   
@M00332:5:000000000-A0TVJ:1:1:13498:26189 2:N:0:1   
ACCACAGCCGCTGCCCATTTGCATAA 
+
```

Using regexp I'm trying to select all lines which contain a specific string `cagccgctgcccatttg`. 
I'm a regex newbie, so I've tried this: `\w{3,}(cagccgctgcccatttg)\w{3,}`

Any help is much appreciated.

Cheers
Simon

Comment: What is the purpose of `\w{3,}` in your regular expression? I know what it means, I just don't understand why you need it to solve your problem.

Comment: Is this DNA sequencing? Adenine (a), Thymine (t), Guanine (g) and Cytosine (c)? Just wondering. Anyways, in JavaScript /(cagccgctgcccatttg)/.test('string') works fine, for string fragments. What editor/environment are you working in?

Comment: so basically i'd like to have lines of only eg.

ACCACAGCCGCTGCCCATTTGCATAA

ACCACAGCCGCTGCCCATTTGCATAA

ACCACAGCCGCTGCCCATTTGCATAA

etc. 

i've used the \w{3,} to indicate that the matched expression is preceeded and succeeded by at least 3 characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to gather all sequences which contain a single sub-sequence. I don't know what environment you're using, but this should return any sequence you're looking for in a very simple way.

```
([ACGT]{3,}CAGCCGCTGCCCATTTG[ACGT]{3,})
```

The brackets are a character class, meaning it matches any single character inside. You don't want to match \w, you only want to match a character if it's one of the 4 you're looking for. Also, you can use parens to cover the whole regex to pick up the entire match.

Comment: wow, you've solved it! thanks a lot, this was really helpful.

Comment: Cool, glad I could help! Be sure to click the check mark next to my answer to accept it, because later on people might not want to answer questions from a person who doesn't accept them. Also, be sure to be very explicit when telling what you're trying to get as output, I think it was confusing for some others at first. And welcome to SO!

Comment: Thanks Sho, I'll do better next time.